# How to automate VBA macro to run through entire file?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA Macro that needs to run through a very large Excel file (about 550,000 rows).

I have found that the Macro can only run through about 20,000 lines at a time - any bigger than that and it gives an 'Overflow' error.

My only solution right now is to set j (row number) = 1 to 20,000, run it, then set j from 20,001 to 40,000, run it, then set j from 40,001 to 60,000 etc....all the way to 550,000.

This is a tedious process and I'm wondering is there any way to automate it so that I don't have to keep going back in to change the numbers?

Code looks something like:

```
Sub ExposedDays()
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim result As String
For j = 2 To 10000
k = 1
Do While Len(Worksheets("my8").Cells(j, k)) > 0
k = k + 1
Loop
Worksheets("my8").Cells(j, 131) = Worksheets("my8").Cells(j, k - 6)
Worksheets("my8").Cells(j, 132) = Worksheets("my8").Cells(j, k - 5)
.......
```

Comment: Can you share a minimum working example?

Comment: Do you have to get the file as an excel file?

Comment: What is j declared as? `Integer` is too small. Try long or double

Comment: share the code and the line it fails on - you probably just needed a larger data type.

Comment: @findwindow has it - go through the code and change all `Dim xxx As Integer` to `...As Long`

Comment: Affirmation from @TimWilliams feels good ^_^

Comment: shared the code...yes i will try changing the integer types to long instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `integer` data type allocates only enough memory to hold integers -32,768 to 32,767. When you:

`dim j as integer`

an 'Overflow' error will result when j exceeds 32,767. To solve this problem you need to assign a larger data type.

The `Long` data type is large enough to hold integers -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
If you:

`dim j as long
 dim k as long`

you should be able to avoid this error.
Hope this helps.